# How to receive additional parameters in @Test (other than the ones obtained from DataProvider)?

Tags: java, testng, dataprovider

I have a @Test testng method, which is receiving input from a Data Provider.

```
@Test (dataProvider = "createData")
public void testMethod(String id, String clientName){
    //some code
  }
```

I need to call the method from external code and pass in a third parameter (independent of DataProvider)

e.g. testMethod("ID887" "clientOne", rowNumber)

But this throws IllegalArgumentException, since the method is receiving only two parameters from DataProvider.

Can a method receive additional arguments?

Answer (score 1):

...as per the documentation, you can use Guice to inject other variables, and it will work with TestNG.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependency-injection

Comment: Instead of using testng DataProvider, we wrote a custom data provider class. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: If you posted a sample implementation of a custom DataProvider here, I would vote for your alternate answer too. :)